# Bootstrap - should each row have container as immediate parent?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I know `column` should have `row` as immediate parent (or, to be precise, `rows` should have only `columns` as ther immediate children) but does `row` must have `container/container-fluid` as immediate parent?

I couldn't find mentioning it in docs and i've seen examples of both: where `rows` do and don't have their respective `containers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the Bootstrap version, and how you want the content aligned, but generally containers are required...

**Version 3.x**

> "Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or
>   .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding."

**Version 4.x**

> "Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap and are
>   required when using our default grid system."

**The top level element of the grid system is the `.row`, and therefore row's should be the *immediate* child of a container.** Bootstrap 4 is more flexible in that rows & columns can be created [without gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters), and the spacing utils can be used to adjust padding and margins.

Comment: you're right, i didn't mention its a bootstrap 4. but you answered my question. thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question which was "should each row have container as immediate parent?". This answer only says that rows are required to be placed inside containers but doesn't say whether it should be immediate parent-child relationship.

Comment: @mist Yes it does answer the question since the top level element of the grid system *is* the `.row`. Not to mention the question was already marked as a duplicate with this answer. Did you really need to downvote this?

Comment: According to the documentation, the rows doesn't have to be immediate child of the container. But cols have to be immediate child of rows. Inspect the themes here and you'll see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/

Comment: I've quoted the docs *"Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap and are required when using our default grid system."* the row *is* the top level element of the grid system. Interpret it whatever way you want @cyonder but do you really think my answer deserves a downvote?

Answer (score 1):

It is not essential that a `row` has a `container` as immediate parent as in some cases it is not possible to have it as immediate parent. But to be consistent with your project you should always have `container` as some parent to the `row` as you may experience alignment and padding problems without it.